# Detecting when a jquery-ui autocomplete pops open with Selenium

Tags: jquery, python, selenium, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm modelling a workflow with selenium/python against a remote webdriver connected to a locally running hub.

The workflow includes entering some text into a search autocomplete and waiting until it pops open with the results.

The closest I got was the following:

```
search_field.send_keys("Search Term")
WebDriverWait(browser, 2).until(
    expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.ui-autocomplete')),
    "Autocomplete didn't pop up"
)
```

This gets me a timeout although I have verified using the browser's DOM inspector that `ul.ui-autocomplete` is present, and I can see the autocomplete still visibly open in the browser after Selenium gives up.

Is my approach wrong overall, or am I just missing an API detail?

Log output:

```
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0/element/28/value {"sessionId": "fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0", "id": "28", "value": ["S", "e", "a", "r", "c", "h", " ", "T", "e", "r", "m"]}
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0/element {"using": "css selector", "sessionId": "fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0", "value": "ul.ui-autocomplete"}
[01/Oct/2015 16:13:06]"GET /myapp/search/?q=Search%20Term HTTP/1.1" 200 136
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:GET http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0/element/29/displayed {"sessionId": "fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0", "id": "29"}
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0/element {"using": "css selector", "sessionId": "fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0", "value": "ul.ui-autocomplete"}
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:GET http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0/element/29/displayed {"sessionId": "fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0", "id": "29"}
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0/element {"using": "css selector", "sessionId": "fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0", "value": "ul.ui-autocomplete"}
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:GET http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0/element/29/displayed {"sessionId": "fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0", "id": "29"}
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0/element {"using": "css selector", "sessionId": "fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0", "value": "ul.ui-autocomplete"}
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:GET http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0/element/29/displayed {"sessionId": "fa48f475-6836-448e-a00a-e04808477fb0", "id": "29"}
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runtests.py", line 237, in <module>
    main()
  File "runtests.py", line 231, in main
    searchTest(browser)
  File "runtests.py", line 214, in createHandout
    Autocomplete didn't pop up
  File "/Users/beha/VEs/product-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Autocomplete didn't pop up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/32921282/5398618, but terle pushed me in the generally right direction. What did it was this here:

```
def selectFromAutocompleteField(browser, search_field, term):
    search_field.send_keys(term)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 2).until(
        firstElementWithCssAttribute('ul.ui-autocomplete', 'display', 'block')
    )
    search_field.send_keys(Keys.DOWN + Keys.RETURN)

def firstElementWithCssAttribute(css, attribute, content):
    def _withCssAttr(browser):
        for elem in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(css):
            if elem and elem.value_of_css_property(attribute) == content:
                return elem
            else:
                continue
        return None

    return _withCssAttr
```

Reason for the inefficient loop construct is that jQuery UI autocomplete creates two different `ul.ui-autocomplete` during use; the first of which will only be used at the first usage, so all of them have to be polled and the first that is visible found later on.

Selenium always returns the first item matching the selection => going for `display:block` after a single find_element only works once, hence the additional loop construct.

Why Selenium’s direct visibility check doesn’t work with Safari (even once, when only one `ul` is present) is a disappointing mystery – but the same could be said about `clear()` on inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could check on properties of the element directly?

Find which Attribute (visibility/enabled/display) gets changed when the AutoComplete-element is shown, and then use that in your `WebDriverWait`.